# Install a 64 bit OS from within a 32 bit OS

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, 64-bit, multi-boot

I am trying to install windows 7 64 bit to be alongside a windows vista 32 bit OS (dual boot). I have tried doing this by booting the CD but when setup gets so far the system does a hard reboot when its not supposed to, so must do it by running setup whilst in an existing windows OS. However the windows OS does not open 64 bit programs.

When booting the CD the setup freezes and reboots right before I am about to hit 'Install now', so it happnes on that screen (screen 2 of setup)

So how can I run the program? I've heard theres QEMU but that is like a VM and is slow, I dont need to install it in a VM as I need full usage of the hardware resources for tasks that need it.

My Computer is x86 so can run 64 and 32 bit OS's, The CPU is an Intel i7-720QM

Comment: x86 CPUs can't run 64-bit programs. What CPU exactly do you have?

Comment: It's an intel  i7-720QM

Comment: Could you edit your post to include some details about your CPU?   Intel?  AMD?  Dual/Quad core?  While there are x86-64 bit CPUs - not all x86 CPUs are 64 bit.   x86 just refers to the instruction set, not necessarily the ability to run 64 bit OS's and apps..

Comment: that should be sufficient to run either 32 or 64 bit..

Comment: what sort of application are you trying to run?  A game?  an application?  something graphically intensive?   or just something that cannot run on a 32 bit system?

Comment: lego worlds, lego digital designer, mspaint, Virtualbox,etc I need more memory that what is on this other laptop (it only has 3GB and 32 bitwindows cant use more than 4gb anyhow) so I figured I should use 64 bit. if I get get the drivers working Ill just replace vista all together

Comment: It seems that your setup cd is broken, try another one, I did lots of dual boot

Comment: ive tried the cd on the other laptop and it works fine, I just did not click 'install'

Answer (score 1):

First your processor is a 64 bit processor, so that you can install both 64-bit os and 32-bit.  You were installing it as a Dual-boot so that there will be no conflicts will occur between OS.

Comment: OP is already trying Dual boot setup and it is failing.

Comment: But that setup can't be failed due to the existing installation of the 32-bit OS.

Comment: It shouldn't fail, but booting from cd crashes the machine for some reason. Try rereading the question to see where the actual problem is.